# Sublime Text 2: Working with multiple documents, building master file

Tags: sublime-text-2, latex, build

I am currently working with LaTeX. I have a big document split up in several sub documents. When I am workin in a sub document, I'd love to compile the master file when pressing ctrl+b, not the file I am currently in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the answer myself! As mentioned [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3108), one just has to put
`%!TEX root = protokoll.tex`
as the first line of the sub documents!

Comment: I really appreciate it!!! This problem has confused me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 different files you need, you can use first-line (or second if you need utf8 stuff) comments.
 I use it to compile the main TeX file from one of the children.

```
%!../main_file.tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}
```

I have a script, which looks at the first line:

```
match=`head -n1 $1 | grep %!`

if [[ $match ]]
    then
        # do stuff with the parent's name, which is ${match:2:100}
    else
        # no match :/
fi
```

and a simple build file aiming at my custom script:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/build/script.sh", "$file"],
    "selector": "whatever"
}
```

This way, you can have as many "references" in your files as you want. Just switch the value of `head -n1`.

To end with, I present to you my XeLaTeX build script ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
flag="-halt-on-error"

match=`head -n1 $file | grep %!`

if [[ $match ]]
    then
        if [ ${match:2:3} = ../ ]
            then
                cd .. &&
                target=${match:5:100}
            else
                target=${match:2:100}
        fi
    else
        target=$file
fi
rubber -c 'set arguments -shell-escape' -f -m xelatex -W all $target

exit 0
```